# What are the differences between normal and insane modes?

Tags: battleblock-theater

What are the differences between the two difficulties? It appears that insane is missing the checkpoints—is that so on every insane level? Are the normal, finale, and encore levels the same otherwise? Is anything else different between "normal" and "insane"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is different about the levels, only the checkpoints are missing so when you die it resets the level.